# Is it okay to group multiple actions in a single http request

Tags: design, architecture, web-development, http

I have a view which displays a list of items related to one thing, it allows creation, removal of, and updates to these items. All changes only persists when the user hits save. Is it okay to group all of these methods into a single request? If not, can you explain why not?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: This isn't something that needs 'fixing', I just wanted design guidance but I guess nvm

Comment: A picture may help to illustrate the issue. Without the picture I do not see the point in bundling these actions. How do you imagine a user to remove and update an item at the same time? Or perform any of the CUD actions simultaneously?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is OK. What you would likely post back to the server is a 'View Model'. This is a model of the data intended to specifically support the view. It does not have to match up 1:1 to your domain model, or implement the same properties / types etc. As a result, it can group multiple concerns together. In fact it would be inefficient not to.

Just keep in mind that your view model should only be used to get data to and from your view, and should be properly mapped to classes that represent your domain model (preferably managed in another layer) before persistence to a database etc.